# How to freeze a changeID on Gerrit?

Tags: git, hook, gerrit

I have a repository on my Gerrit server where a changeID has to be tested for some hours, after it is reviewed and ready to be submitted.

While testing the changeID to be submitted, I would like to freeze/hook the changeID, so that nobody pushes new Patch-sets or rebases.

When the testing step is finished it should be possible to submit this changeID, but for that, it would be desirable that the concerned changeID do not have any new patch-sets after starting the testing step.

---

Currently, when somebody creates a new patch-set on a ChangeID which I've already started to test, I've 2 choices:

1) Start to test again with the new patch-set, what delays my work.
2) Ignore the new patch-set and execute cherry-pick specifically from the patch-set which I've started to test and when finished the tests, push it for refs/heads/master.

Comment: Why are others updating your patch sets? Each developer should submit their own change. Is updating others changes a normal part of your workflow?

Comment: Yes, here we often work in pair (driver/navigator) switching positions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Gerrit administrator for your Gerrit server would need to setup an additional custom label that uses the function "PatchSetLock". This would look like another code review choice and, when set, would prevent new patches from being added to that change-id.

Your administrator would also need to set the project ACLS so that developers had permission to edit the label. Similar to what is likely already setup for the code-review label.

Details are here:
https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-labels.html